# Dependency mediation fails in play

Tags: java, maven, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I got  play application that pulls in a lot of external resources. but the version mapping does not work.

Normally I work on a mac, but now I had to set the environment up on windows and this is where it started to fail.

I got Java, maven, play and sbt set up (and working afik). Still, I'm having an issue where the dependency mediation all of a sudden just stops.

Output from one of these failed dependecies:

```
   [debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: 
    dependency: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.11 {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => 
    dependency: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;${version.org.codehaus.jackson} {compile=[compile(*), master(*)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
```

seems as on the mediation fails, the version (1.9.11) is clearly found, but the mediation never seems to give me a version number, just a class reference or something.

As you probably figured out by now, I'm a play no0b, I don't really know if this is due to some differences in the configuration between Mac OSX and Windows, or being a known issue in any of the libs mentioned above.

I also tried to set the version directly in the Build.scala, but no success :-(

```
        "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-mapper-asl" % "1.9.11" force()
```

If any of you could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful indeed.

**Edit**: Forgot to add the actual error I get:

```
    [error] unresolved dependency: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;${version.org.codehaus.jackson}: not found
```

It seems to me that the version number is never resolved. A sucessful mediation will resolve a version number like:

```
     [debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: 
    dependency: org.mockito#mockito-all;${version.org.mockito} {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]} => 
    dependency: org.mockito#mockito-all;1.9.5 {test=[runtime(*), master(*)]}
```

This gives me *org.mockito#mockito-all;1.9.5*, not just an unresolves string.

Bard

Comment: I don't seem to find the issue? What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for getting back to me.